# How do I focus a widget?

Tags: haskell, wxhaskell

When I start my application I want to set the focus on a certain button. Currently I need to hit `tab` once to have the button focused.

The `wxwidgets` documents mention a `SetFocus` method ([link](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a697f9f8d3ff389790f1c74b59bcb1d75)) which doesn't seem to be available in `wxhaskell`?

Then I found `MoveBeforeInTabOrder` ([link](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#af2b92f61cd9f9e2e0efe4cce307e25b1)) but again, I didn't find it in `wxhaskell`.

A maintainer of `wxhaskell` [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/601996/348201) it is a 'fairly complete GUI binding' in 2009 so am I just missing something here or is it bad luck?

Here is my minimal example:

```
module Main where

import Graphics.UI.WX
import Graphics.UI.WXCore

main :: IO ()
main = start hello

hello :: IO ()
hello = do
  f <- frame []
  test <- button f [ text := "button" ]
  set f [ layout := widget test ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wx library has a [`focusOn` function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wx-0.92.1.0/docs/Graphics-UI-WX-Controls.html#v:focusOn) that allows you to focus on a control.

It is a re-export of [wxcore's `windowSetFocus`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wxcore-0.92.2.0/docs/Graphics-UI-WXCore-WxcClassesMZ.html#v:windowSetFocus). The type is a bit misleading: it says `Window a`, but it works for buttons because [they are windows too](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html).

The following works (note I only added the last line):

```
module Main where

import Graphics.UI.WX
import Graphics.UI.WXCore

main :: IO ()
main = start hello

hello :: IO ()
hello = do
  f <- frame []
  test <- button f [ text := "button" ]
  set f [ layout := widget test ]
  focusOn test                          -- Here!
```